# Is it necessary for shopping cart to be displayed twice?

Tags: usability, gui-design, e-commerce

I read somewhere that shopping cart has to be displayed twice on the page so it would be easy for the user to find it. Also I read that shopping cart should always be visible.

So what is the best practice to place shopping cart on the page?

For example this website http://kapitele.com.ua/ has a bottom bar that is floating. Thus, shopping cart is always visible. But http://www.bestbuy.com has only one shopping cart in the header. Would you say that the first website is more usable in terms of finding a cart and continuing to the order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good and bad are subjective terms, try to think about it from what the user may need.

For example, if your product pages are lengthy, with many products, then it could make sense to have the basket/cart as a summary at the top of the page, which travels with the user as they scroll down through the products, allowing them ease to see the value and items in the basket.

If, however, the category, page or simply the total number of products the company has to offer is very few, then it makes little sense to clutter up the interface and use up real-estate to show two basket/cart summaries in the same view.